# Send Microsoft Graph api results to Azure Event hub

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-eventhub

I have the following Powershell code that queries a Microsoft Graph api endpoint. 
I need to find away of sending this results to an Azure Event hub

```
$ClientID       = "826fc487-212b-4e45-9fbb-8059e4b5d3ce"        # Should be a ~36 hex character string; insert your info here
$ClientSecret   = "9OOrzJ90Kvv97BZ3DQLQXgI/wFezmnJ8DRFMh7K/9Fs="    # Should be a ~44 character string; insert your info here
$tenantdomain   = "tenant.onmicrosoft.com"    # For example, contoso.onmicrosoft.com

$loginURL       = "https://login.microsoft.com"
$resource       = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

$body       = @{grant_type="client_credentials";resource=$resource;client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
$oauth      = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $loginURL/$tenantdomain/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Body $body


Write-Output $oauth

if ($oauth.access_token -ne $null) {
    $headerParams = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}

    $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents"
    Write-Output $url

    $myReport = (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headerParams -Uri $url)

    foreach ($event in $myReport.Content){
    $SasToken="uGllYoYHJ4etHsTh7yETy6CKFegebfXK4x3e9Lbw4+k="
        Write-Output $event

    }

} else {
    Write-Host "ERROR: No Access Token"
}
```

please any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more close to the Azure Event hub but not Graph, azure event hub doesn't provide directly way to send events by PowerShell(known way is NET/GO/Python), we can create an custom PowerShell Binary Module by C#, and handle the NET version "send events by PowerShell" in the **ProcessRecord** method.

> Reference a blog from **Michael Sorens** to let you know how to create net powershell module: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/

Another official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-binary-module